# Unzip command doesn't work in script when run on boot

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, zip

I have the following bash script:

```
FILE=/home/pi/kpidry/test.zip
if test -f "$FILE"; 
then
    echo "$FILE exists"
    rm -r /home/pi/test/*
    unzip /home/pi/kpidry/test.zip -d /home/pi/test/
    rm -r /home/pi/kpidry/test.zip
fi
exit 0
```

The script runs fine when I run it manually, and executes all the commands as expected. However, I have added a line to rc.local in order to run the script on boot. When that runs, it executes every line except the unzip line. 
Could this be because the unzip program is not yet running? If so, can I run it manually in rc.local?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Likely because it is not in the PATH. Tried to give the full path (`/usr/bin/zip` or whatever)?

Comment: "_Could this be because the unzip program is not yet running_" - this suggests a misunderstanding. The `unzip` program only runs while it's doing something. (It's not started like a Windows "service" and left to sit around until needed.)

Comment: @roaima did you mean service?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes - I avoided referring to a UNIX/Linux dæmon in case that terminology was unfamiliar.

Comment: @roaima it is still a service, a daemon is a slightly different concept. Yes most services are daemons, but not always. I have a service running on by machine that is not, it is logging to `stdout`.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `sleep #` at the top of the script where # is an amount of time to wait so that everything is set in the environment before the rest of the commands actually run?

Answer (score 1):

I think files from /usr/bin/ are not guaranteed to be available at boot-time:

> /usr/bin is a standard directory on Unix-like operating systems that contains most of the executable files (i.e., ready-to-run programs) that are not needed for booting (i.e., starting) or repairing the system.
>   (ref: http://www.linfo.org/usr_bin.html )

Try calling "/usr/bin/unzip" instead of unzip.

If the call comes late enough and /usr/bin/ is mounted by that time and it was just the PATH environment that was missing, that could work.

Comment: It is true, that `/usr` is not guaranteed to be mounted early in the boot. However if you know that it is (such as in the standard install of raspbian), then you could add it to the PATH or access it via `/usr/bin/unzip`. (And I think debian is planning to or has merged `/usr` with the main file-system.

Comment: A typical Pi installation has `/usr` included as part of `/`. Also see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1018649/332907) and [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/).

Comment: If it were a matter of `unzip` not being available because `/usr/bin` wasn't available due to the PATH not being added to the environment yet then the the lines before and after it wouldn't run either because `rm` is also in `/usr/bin`. If I'm missing something here then `sleep` could be added to the top of the script to allow time everything to be set in the environment.

Comment: `$ which rm`

`/bin/rm`